# How I can get computer connected domain name

Tags: node.js, electron

I have been trying to fetch computer connected domain name - its pretty straight forward in C# but struggling to find solution for same in electron.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.domainname?view=net-7.0#system-net-networkinformation-ipglobalproperties-domainname

```
function getCurrentUserDomain() {
  const username = os.userInfo().username;
  console.log('Current User Name:', username);
  const domainArray = username.split('\');
  const domain = domainArray.length > 1 ? domainArray[0] : null;
  console.log('Current User Domain:', domain);
  console.log('Current User Host Name:', os.hostname);
  return os.hostname;
}
```

I am able to just retrieve either user name or just device name not domain name.

Comment: .net had a bunch wrappers to win32 api which electron dont have out of the box. additionally the "computer name" and "domain name" do not translate well across operating system. you will need to rely on windows executable such as [`whoami`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/whoami).

Comment: Thanks, seems we can get this suggestion working on windows atleast